# Как перехватить исключения переполнения массива?

Tags: c++, массивы, исключения

Пытаюсь перехватить исключение переполнения массива, но когда доходит до элемента который нужно обработать компилятор пропускает блок catch.
Ошибка: Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'Array' was corrupted.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void Array()
{
    const int n = 6;
    int Array[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        try {
            if (i == 7) throw 7;
            Array[i] = rand() % 10 + 1;
        }
        catch(int k)
        {
            cout << k;
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            i = 5;
            cout << "Stack overflow\n";
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    Array();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну так вы же не перехватываете `i == 6`, вот и получаете выход за пределы массива! Массив-то у вас `int Array[6];`... UB, и дальше может быть все, что угодно...

Comment: вообще то try-catch  в общем случае не умеет перехватывать выход за пределы массива. Хотите иметь такую возможность - используйте std::vector + at

Comment: @KoVadim Он перехватывает вручную: ` if (i == 7) throw 7;`. Только не то, что надо...

Comment: ага, слона я не увидел

Comment: @Harry  `if (i == 7) throw 7;` добавлен просто так. Я ожидаю вывод в консоль следующего
_Stack overflow
7
Stack overflow_

Comment: Просто при обращении к `Array[6]` вы обращаетесь за пределы выделенной памяти, портите стек, получаете UB... Вы вообще в курсе, что  раз вы объявили `int Array[6];`, то можете обращаться к элементам `Array[0] .. Array[5]`, а `Array[6]` - это уже за пределами выделенной для массива памяти?